# Js одна функция подменяет значения, используемые другой

Tags: javascript, функции, canvas

```js
class Primitive {
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  parsePoints(line) {
    let array = line.split(' ');
    let points = array.map(function(value) {
      let point = value.split(',');
      point[0] = Number(point[0]);
      point[1] = Number(point[1]);
      return point;
    });
    return points;
  }

  moverLine(points) {
    this.ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
    for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      this.ctx.lineTo(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
    }
  }

  line(points, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
    points = this.parsePoints(points);
    this.ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    this.moverLine(points);
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.ctx.closePath();
  }

  strokeCircle(x, y, r, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
    this.ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }

  strokePolygon(points, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
    points = this.parsePoints(points);
    this.ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    console.log(this.ctx.strokeStyle);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.moverLine(points);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }

  strokeRect(x, y, w, h, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
    this.ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    this.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
  }

  fillCircle(x, y, r, fillStyle) {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fill();
  }

  fillPolygon(points, fillStyle) {
    points = this.parsePoints(points);
    this.ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.moverLine(points);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fill();
  }

  fillRect(x, y, w, h, fillStyle) {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    this.ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  }

  fillText(text, x, y, font, fillStyle) {
    this.ctx.font = font;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    this.ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
  }

  superRect(x, y, w, h, fillStyle, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
    this.fillRect(x, y, w, h, fillStyle);
    this.strokeRect(x, y, w, h, lineWidth, strokeStyle);
  }

  superPolygon(points, fillStyle, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
    this.fillPolygon(points, fillStyle);
    this.strokePolygon(points, lineWidth, strokeStyle);
  }

  superCircle(x, y, r, fillStyle, lineWidth, strokeStyle) {
    this.fillCircle(x, y, r, fillStyle);
    this.strokeCircle(x, y, r, lineWidth, strokeStyle);
  }
}
let primitive = new Primitive(document.getElementById('imgCanvas').getContext('2d'));

class CreateObj {
  template(type, color) {
    return {
      'type': type,
      'disable': false
    };
  }
  polygon(points, internalCol, externalCol, lineWidth) {
    let template = this.template('polygon');
    template.points = points;
    template.internalCol = internalCol;
    template.externalCol = externalCol;
    template.line = lineWidth;
    return template;
  }
}
let obj = new CreateObj;
let p = obj.polygon('300,300 30,30 420,30', '#ff0000', '#000000', 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(p, '', ' '));
primitive.superPolygon(p.points, p.internalCol, p.line, p.externalCol);
let figures = [];
figures.push({
  'type': 'rect',
  'x': 360,
  'y': 270,
  'width': 200,
  'height': 100,
  'disable': false,
  'border': {
    'width': 3,
    'color': 'black',
  },
  'area': {
    'color': 'blue',
  }
});

function dr() {
  for (let fig of figures) {
    if (!fig.disable) {
      primitive.superRect(fig.x, fig.y, fig.width, fig.height, fig.area.color, fig.border.width, fig.border.color);
    }
  }
}
primitive.line('60,330 270,330', 3, 'green');
primitive.superCircle(165, 30, 15, '#ff0ff0', 3, '#000000');
primitive.superPolygon('135,90 165,300 195,90', 'red', 3, 'black');
primitive.superRect(60, 360, 210, 90, 'blue', 3, 'black');
primitive.fillText('Primitive test', 75, 415, '30px tahoma', 'black');
dr();
```

```html
<canvas id="imgCanvas" width="660" height="660" style="border: 2px solid black"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stacksnippets.net/js"></script>
```

Работаю с `canvas`, а значит его контекст - объект, доступный по ссылке.

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
```

Есть две функции к примеру:

```
function r1(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    //код рисования...
}

function r2(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'magenta';
    //код рисования два...
}
```

Функции вызываются в записанном порядке, то есть:

```
r1();
r2();
```

Как уже упоминалось `ctx - объект`, доступный по ссылке.

Интерпретатор начинает выполнять первую функцию, но мы же знаем, что он побежит дальше по коду, не дожидаясь завершения первой функции начнет исполнение второй.

И получаем - функции исполняются параллельно.

Они взаимодействуют с объектом `ctx`, с одним и тем же объектом, в результате чего получаю каверзный баг, если так можно выразиться.

Первая функция для своих нужд определяет свойство `fillStyle` объекта `ctx` как `red`, вторая функция для своих нужд как `magenta`. После чего первая функция начинает рисовать используя объект `ctx`, но так, как вторая функция случайным образом подменила значения первая функция нарисует не красный квадрат, а фиолетовый.

И наконец вопрос: как решить эту проблему?

> P.S   Наиболее правильно и изящно, но буду рад любому решению.

Comment: "мы же знаем, что он побежит дальше по коду, не дожидаясь завершения первой функции начнет исполнение второй." - я, например, этого не знаю. Кто такие "мы"?

Comment: @Igor Где-то читал, про то, что он побежит;  Мы - это я и то, что я читал; И когда отключаю вторую функцию оно работает нормально, подставлю любую другую очень мелку функцию(не больше убираемой) у которой есть изменение `fillStyle`результат тотже;

Comment: Вы стали жертвой явления, которое я называю "размножение незнания через интернет".

Comment: @Igor вполне возможно, не буду спорить, но обьясните пожалуйста почему тогда так случается ведб цвет подменился, даже весь код оставил, чтоб вы посмотрели ( и да это бред а не код )

Comment: Создайте в вопросе работающий пример, воспроизводящий поведение, которое Вы наблюдаете.

Comment: @Igor сделанноо

Comment: Пример слишком заумный, я просмотрел каждую отрисованную фигуру, но так и не понял, что именно в нём не так

Comment: @andreymal да согласан код фигня там есть зеленая линия. и большой красный треугольник с зеленой обводкой в коде ему задавалась черная обводка, но она зеленая

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук строчка `primitive.line('60,330 270,330', 3, 'green');` рисует очень даже зелёную линию поверх вашего треугольника с чёрной обводной

Comment: А вот *почему* она рисует линию поверх треугольника — вот это уже действительно интересный вопрос. Но как минимум fillStyle здесь точно ни при чём

Comment: Цвет какой фигуры отличaется от ожидаемого?

Comment: fillstyle как пример был

Comment: сейчас буду постепенно удалять лишние фигуры

Comment: @ЕвгенийБабийчук пример неверный, он не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме. Вы просто забыли вызвать `beginPath()` внутри метода `line`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо